# Dropdown doesn't update Rep Changes

Tags: bug, reputation, live-refresh, activity-dropdown

I've had this issue for a while and am surprised that nobody has asked about it here.

Sometimes, while waiting for a new question on the SO frontpage, I notice that my rep changes a little. Curious as to which post earned me that delta-rep, I mouseover my username to see the latest rep-change. When I do this, I don't see any new rep changes. Refreshing the browser clears this problem and the dropdown is now populated with the latest rep changes.

Is this a bug in SO, or a browser specific thing or… ?

I'm using Mac OSX 10.7.5 and viewing SO on a dedicated fluid.app app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdown is loaded via an AJAX request, and then cached for a while.  If you wait a little, then try again, a fresh copy is loaded, I believe.

The dropdown was never designed to auto-update though.

The URL loaded does include a cache-busting id

```
http://<site-url>/users/profile-link-stats?_=1353432401917
```

and in theory the web-socket live-refresh code could bump that number once in a while to ensure a fresh copy is loaded. Loading the drop-down is, relatively speaking, a heavier operation for the servers, though.

Answer (score 0):

The drop-down is not one of the things that gets updated via live-refresh. Only the reputation number at the very top gets updated. You'll also notice that your reputation in the user box on an actual post does not get updated live either.