# Daily rep total in user page doesn't update

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-graph, activity-dropdown

This is somewhat related to [one of my earlier questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156247/dropdown-doesnt-update-rep-changes). I noticed today, that when I refreshed my user page, my dropdown showed updates to my daily rep total that were not present in my `user>reputation` section (as seen in the image below). Why is this happening?

[image: inconsistent daily-rep update]

Comment: Displays 215 for me when I view your profile graph, so it's probably just caching.

Comment: Perhaps you should check in private mode. That way you can easily see if its a caching problem

Comment: The answer is always caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These values are cached for 10 minutes (not doing so == insane summation load), your graph may take up to this long to update...it's fine now.